# Radiobutton in Android Quiz app

Tags: java, android, android-radiobutton

I am working on quiz app for Android and I use RadioButtons in RadioGroup. I want to achieve that when someone checks the right answer (this case its `id/krzyzyk`) the score will increase by one point. I made this code:

```
int score = 2;

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    RadioButton radiobutton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.krzyzyk);

    if (radiobutton1.isChecked()) {
        score = score + 1;
    }
}
```

It works but when I run the app and click in another RadioButton and again `id/krzyzyk` the score will update again. Can you help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will always increment the score when the user taps on the RadioButton `krzyzyk`.

**I'll suggest you to Submit the answer and go to the next question incrementing the score if the selected RadioButton is correct.**

Change your code to something like:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.correct_answer: // this is id/krzyzyk
            if (checked)
                score++;
                // Go to next question
            break;
        case R.id.wrong_answer:
            if (checked)
                // Go to next question.
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code earlier but it doesnt work fine. 

If i chcek `correct_answer` than `wrong_answer` and again `correct_answer` the app will increase score twice, not only once.

Comment: After any RadioButton is clicked you should redirect to the next question and clean your variables resetting your booleans to false, and wait for the next user tap.

Comment: Ok i found solution, `onResume()` helped

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the RadioButton or RadioGroup by `setEnabled(boolean)`.

For example, you could disable the radio button that was selected by

```
radiobutton1.setEnabled(false);
```

I would suggest disabling all the radio buttons at that point, to prevent a user from changing their answer. You could do this all at once by calling `setEnabled(boolean)` on the radio group.

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
group.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have think about logic of your quiz, of course score will  be increase because when you choose right answer and check this in listener ( this method calls on every click on button), it will be wrong result, maybe can you try make isChecked when you click on button (Next, Check) or swipe fragment with question, or you can use some variable like flag of wrong-right indicator,

```
int m_rightAnswer =0;
...
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
   RadioButton radiobutton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.krzyzyk);

    if (radiobutton1.isChecked() && m_rightAnswer==0){
        score = score + 1; m_rightAnswer=1 }
              }
```

It's working only once, when you click on right answer, and when you click any radio button and return on right your score don't change, but it doesn't have logic